# How to link Excel Data in Different cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to link the receipt vouchers paid to the invoices number, 
Using `=VLOOKUP(C6;[Sheet2]$A$1:$G$1000;2;FALSE)` helps when the "invoice number" is in column A, while in my case the "receipt voucher" number is in column A and the invoices numbers are in columns C, E, F G.. etc.. (depending on how many invoices are paid using the same receipt voucher)

Clarification:

assume I have issued 9 invoices (#1-#9) to my customers. Their amounts and details are as below:

```
Amount    Customer    Date        Invoice #    
100      Customer A   15-Oct-16      1   
 25      Customer B   16-Oct-16      2   
123      Customer A   17-Oct-16      3   
100      Customer A   18-Oct-16      4   
 11      Customer C   19-Oct-16      5   
100      Customer A   20-Oct-16      6   
 90      Customer A   21-Oct-16      7   
 50      Customer A   22-Oct-16      8   
160      Customer B   23-Oct-16      9
```

(This is the format my POS system issues in, column A is the amount, Column B is the customer name, column C is the date and column D is the invoice number)

and I am making another excel file for the receipt vouchers that I issue when I got the payment, a voucher might be for one or more invoices as below:

```
Receipt voucher #   Date        Amount    Invoices Paid by the voucher          
  33              15-Nov-16    125.00          1   2       
  45              17-Nov-16    223.00          3   4       
  55              18-Nov-16     11.00          5           
 123              20-Nov-16    400.00          6   7   8   9
```

now my question is, when I enter the data in the receipt voucher details file (in the second table), how can I make excel put the receipt voucher number beside the related invoice number in the first table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AGGREGATE():

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW(Sheet2!$D$2:$I$100)/(Sheet2!$D$2:$I$100=D2);1))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know you,,, but you are a programming God!!!!! Thank you very very much for this kind help, it took me really long time without being able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when using `vlookup` the focus (your `C6`) should be at the beginning of the table being looked up. Personally, if you can, I would do it this way...
with receipt voucher column using this lookup after fixing the receipt voucher table `=vlookup(D2,[Sheet2]$A$1:$G$1000,2,FALSE)`
This should go in column E of the invoice table.

Invoice Table:

```
  A          B           C              D                E 
Amount    Customer      Date     (D1) Invoice #     Receipt Voucher #
100      Customer A   15-Oct-16    (D2) 1                33 
 25      Customer B   16-Oct-16         2                33
123      Customer A   17-Oct-16         3                45
100      Customer A   18-Oct-16         4                45
 11      Customer C   19-Oct-16         5                55
100      Customer A   20-Oct-16         6                123
 90      Customer A   21-Oct-16         7                123   
 50      Customer A   22-Oct-16         8                123   
160      Customer B   23-Oct-16         9                123
```

Receipt Voucher table: reconfigured to have invoices paid in first column

```
Invoices Paid by Voucher(A1)     Receipt voucher #   Date        Amount    
 1 (this is in A2)                   33              15-Nov-16    105.00 
 2                                   33              15-Nov-16     25.00
 3                                   45              17-Nov-16    123.00         
 4                                   45              17-Nov-16    100.00         
 5                                   55              18-Nov-16     11.00         
 6                                  123              20-Nov-16    100.00         
 7                                  123              20-Nov-16     90.00         
 8                                  123              20-Nov-16     50.00         
 9                                  123              20-Nov-16    160.00
```

Keep the invoices paid by the voucher separate...it can't look them up if they're all in 1 column together.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a good idea though it will make the "vouchers" sheet excessively long as I will repeat the same information for each invoice paid.I have tried the INDEX MATCH formulas, Maybe I can fine tune it in a way that works as intended. Thanks a lot for the help